# Move columns based upon viewport using media queries?

Tags: html, css

As a test, I created 4 columns (with corresponding colors) with 25% width each. I floated them so that they will span the entirety of the page side by side.

I wanted to use media queries in order to cause there to only be two columns side by side if the viewport became small enough, and then one per line if the viewport was even smaller. I'm just doing this within one HTML document as I don't really care to create an accompanying CSS document.

```
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <style>
        @media only screen and (max-width: 787px) {
            .column1, .column2, .column3, .column4 {
                width: 50%;
            }
        }

        @media only screen and (max-width: 420px) {
            .column1, .column2, .column3, .column4 {
                width: 100%;
            }
        }

        .column1, .column2, .column3, .column4 {
            width: 25%;
            height: 300px;
        }
        .column1 {
            background-color: red;
            float: left;
        }
        .column2 {
            background-color: blue;
            float: left;
        }
        .column3 {
            background-color: yellow;
            float: right;
        }
        .column4 {
            background-color: black;
            float: right;
            color: white;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="column1">
        <p>breakfast</p>
    </div>

    <div class="column2">
        <p>lunch</p>
    </div>

    <div class="column3">
        <p>dinner</p>
    </div>

    <div class="column4">
        <p>snack</p>
    </div>
</body>
```

I feel like I am doing something incredibly wrong. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

media queries should be below your css styles and not above them.
check this fiddle ~ https://jsfiddle.net/g4j4ewpp/

```
.column1,
  .column2,
  .column3,
  .column4 {
    width: 25%;
    height: 300px;
  }

  .column1 {
    background-color: red;
    float: left;
  }

  .column2 {
    background-color: blue;
    float: left;
  }

  .column3 {
    background-color: yellow;
    float: right;
  }

  .column4 {
    background-color: black;
    float: right;
    color: white;
  }

  @media only screen and (max-width: 787px) {
    .column1,
    .column2,
    .column3,
    .column4 {
      width: 50%;
    }
  }

  @media only screen and (max-width: 420px) {
    .column1,
    .column2,
    .column3,
    .column4 {
      width: 100%;
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

An explanation for the answer provided by GvM -

The browser parses code top to bottom. You could have two thousand

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 748px){
    .class {
        background-color: some-color;
        height: some-height;
     }
}
```

statements. As long as they are all for the same height, the last one will take effect and all previous will be ignored.

Also, say you have three queries that set particular attributes you might want if its a medium size, and one extra if it is a large size.

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 320px) {
    /*give a div 40px height and blue text*/
    .this-div {
        color: blue;
        height: 40px;
        background-color: lemonchiffon;
    }

    /*declare a div, but hide it until the screen is big enough*/
    .hidden-div {
        display: none;
        width: 50%;
        background-color: orange;
    }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 480px) {
    /*style a different div to have blue text and assign it height*/
    .that-div {
        color: blue;
        height: 30%;
        background-color: magenta;
    }

    /*change the first div's font to red, but keep its height the same*/
    .this-div {
        color: red;
    }

@media only screen and (min-width: 748px) {
    /*change the first div's font again, and now it takes up the entire screen.*/
    .this-div {
        color: green;
        height: 100%;
    }

    /*split the second div and a new third div*/
    .that-div {
        width: 50%;
    }

    .hidden-div {
        display: inline;
    }
}
```

The background colors remained the same through all media queries. But, the heights and widths may have changed depending on which query was most recently accepted - depending on the size of the viewport.